# Xamarin Android - Actionbar icon padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms

I have styled the action bar in my application, however it looks different on Android KitKat (right device) and Android Lollipop (left device), as you can see on the picture:

[image: icon-paddings]

I want to add some icon padding(left, right) to make it same as on Lollipop. Any ideas how to modify following XML files?

**Resources/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Resources/values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
      <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: How do you hided the application icon? i'm not able to hide the app icon without having some action bar layout issue with the hamburger icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resources/values/styles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:logo">@drawable/actionBarIcon</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Resources/drawable/actionBarIcon.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:right="10dp" android:left="10dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: **Error:** _No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:logo' with value '@drawable/actionBarIcon')._  It is strange, because file **actionBarIcon.xml** is in the **drawable** folder, so it should work...

Comment: Try to set all letters to lowercase.

Comment: After changing it to lowercase, the error has disappeared but it doesn't work :(.

Comment: Well it works, but if I create a new instance of new NavigationPage(detailPage), then all styles are somehow replaced...

Comment: Can you give some details about it? It shouldn't change any styles.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I had some issues in XML files. Now it is working. Thanks.

Comment: I can not, for the life of me, get this to work. Now I AM setting the Master property to a page whose Icon property is defined (this is what has no padding) but my understanding was that this was the correct way to set the "hamburger menu" icon. Is this wrong?

Comment: Don't work... I have added the styles.xml and actionbaricon.xml (lowercase), changed also actionbaricon in styles.xml to lowercase - seems to have no effect. I think, that ic_launcher in actionbaricon.xml has to be repleaced with the name of the menu-image (in my case Home.png -> @drawable/Home) - correct? I see no difference, if i set /Home or /ic_launcher -> so I think, the xml's are not used. Do I have to do more..?